# JPA join two secondary tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm having these five tables:

```
REF_CT          REF_CT_L        REF_ST        REF_ST_L
======          ========        ======        ========
CT_ID           CT_ID           ST_ID         ST_ID
ST_ID           LANGUAGE_ID     NAME          LANGUAGE_ID
NAME            NAME            REF_CODE      NAME
REF_CODE        DESCRIPTION                   DESCRIPTION


REF_LANGUAGE
============
LANGUAGE_ID
LOCALE_CODE
NAME
```

By using JPA, I have created these three entity classes:

1. Class common.contact.City

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "REF_CT")
   @SecondaryTable(name = "REF_CT_L")
   public class City implements Reference {
      @Id
      @Column(name = "CT_ID")
      @TableGenerator(name = "TABLE_GEN", table = "SYS_SEQ",
           pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_VALUE", pkColumnValue =   "CITY_SEQ")
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "TABLE_GEN")
      private Integer id;

      @Column(name = "NAME")
      private String name;

      @Column(table = "REF_CT_L", name = "NAME")
      private String value;

      @Column(name = "REF_CODE")
      private String refCode;

      @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Language.class)
      @JoinColumn(table = "REF_CT_L", name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
      private Language language;

      @ManyToOne(targetEntity = State.class, optional = true)
      @JoinColumn(name = "ST_ID", referencedColumnName = "ST_ID")
      private State state;
   ```
2. Class common.contact.State

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "REF_ST")
   @SecondaryTable(name = "REF_ST_L")
   public class State implements Reference {
      @Id
      @Column(name = "ST_ID")
      @TableGenerator(name = "TABLE_GEN", table = "SYS_SEQ",
           pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_VALUE", pkColumnValue = "STATE_SEQ")
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "TABLE_GEN")
      private Integer id;

      @Column(name = "NAME")
      private String name;

      @Column(table = "REF_ST_L", name = "NAME")
      private String value;

      @Column(name = "REF_CODE")
      private String refCode;

      @OneToMany(targetEntity = City.class, mappedBy = "state")
      private Set<City> cities;

      @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Language.class)
      @JoinColumn(table = "REF_ST_L", name = "LANGUAGE_ID", unique = true, referencedColumnName = "LANGUAGE_ID")
      private Language language;
   ```
3. Class common.system.Language

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "SYS_LANGUAGE")
   public class Language implements BaseEntity {
      @Id
      @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
      @TableGenerator(name = "TABLE_GEN", table = "SYS_SEQ",
           pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_VALUE", pkColumnValue = "LANGUAGE_SEQ")
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "TABLE_GEN")
      private Integer id;

      @Column(name = "LOCALE_CODE")
      private String locale;

      @Column(name = "NAME")
      private String name;
   ```

But when I tried to run this query

```
select city from City city where city.id = 1
```

I'm getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 10, for class: common.contact.State
```

FYI, the following data is added:

REF_CT

```
CT_ID    ST_ID    NAME    REF_CODE
=====    =====    ====    ========
  1        10    CHERAS     CHE
```

REF_CT_L

```
CT_ID    LANGUAGE_ID    NAME       DESCRIPTION
=====    ===========    ====       ===========
  1           1      BANDAR CHERAS  CHERAS BARU
  1           2      CHERAS TOWN    NEW CHERAS
```

REF_ST

```
ST_ID    NAME     REF_CODE
=====    ====     ========
  10    SELANGOR    SEL
```

REF_ST_L

```
ST_ID    LANGUAGE_ID     NAME      DESCRIPTION
=====    ===========     ====      ===========
  10          1        SELANGOR    SELANGOR BARU
  10          2        SERIANGOR   NEW SERIANGOR
```

REF_LANGUAGE

```
LANGUAGE_ID    LOCALE_CODE    NAME
===========    ===========    ====
     1           ms_En       Malay
     2           en_US       English
```

The generated SQL was:

```
SELECT state0_.st_id AS st1_50_0_,
       state0_.NAME AS name50_0_, state0_.ref_code AS ref4_50_0_,
       state0_1_.language_id AS language2_51_0_, state0_1_.NAME AS name51_0_
  FROM ref_st state0_ LEFT OUTER JOIN ref_st_l state0_1_
       ON state0_.st_id = state0_1_.st_id
 WHERE state0_.st_id = 10;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is producing a LEFT JOIN because you set the City -> State relationship as optional.  Change it to not-nullable and you should get an inner join which should resolve the multiple rows returning.

common.contact.City ->

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = State.class, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ST_ID", referencedColumnName = "ST_ID", nullable = false)
private State state;
```

Comment: The problem is still persist. It still shows More than one row with the given identifier was found: 10, for class: common.contact.State

Comment: Can you show the generated SQL for the query to confirm it's no longer performing a LEFT JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

"REF_ST" has a one-to-many relationship with "REF_ST_L". This means that "REF_ST_L" cannot be mapped as a secondary table (which implies a one-to-one relationship).

Same logic is valid for "REF_CT" -> "REF_CT_L".